# If you are using the Java Stream API, how do you print out a Map of Lists following after calling reduce?

Tags: java, exception, arraylist, stream, mapreduce

So, as of now, I am trying to read Strings into a Stream, and then eventually use the output. As of now, the only goal is simply to print it out without errors, but so far I am having no luck. Essentially, all I'm trying to do, is take a list of Strings and convert them into a map. I'm running into two different issues. One, my code triggers a `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` on the line below containing `current.get(item).addAll(update.get(item));` and two, I ultimately want to produce a Map that I can use once the stream is done processing. I thought that is what the `reduce` method was for, but I'm not sure how to use the Map I'm trying to produce here after the stream has closed. Suppose you have a text file `string.txt` that looks like:

```
A,a,ab,abc
B,b,bc,bdc
```

Ideally the output would be a map of lists similar to this:

```
{"A"=["a","ab","abd"], "B"=["b","bc","bcd"]}
```

My code looks similar to the following:

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String path = "path/to/strings.txt";
        try (Stream<String> stringStream = Files.lines(Paths.get(path))) {
            stream.limit(5).filter(e -> {
                return (e.split(",").length == 2);
            }).map(e -> {
                String[] elements = e.split(",");
                Map<String, List<String>> eMap = new HashMap<String,List<String>>();
                eMap.put(elements[0], Arrays.asList(elements[1]));
                return eMap;
            }).reduce(new HashMap<String,List<String>>(), (current, update) -> {
                for(String item : update.keySet()){
                    if(current.containsKey(item)){
                        // ERROR HERE:
                        current.get(item).addAll(update.get(item));
                    }else{
                        // ERROR HERE:
                        current.put(item, update.get(item));
                    }
                }
                return current;
            });

            // ERROR HERE:
            System.out.println(stringStream);
            // Result: java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@XXXXXXXXXX
            // Expected: {"A"=["a","ab","abd"], "B"=["b","bc","bcd"]} 

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  
}
```

I would really appreciate any help that you can provide! Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the point of the stream processing when you don't grab the final value returned by `reduce()`:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how the example would work.

- First map the stream to two elements by doing a limited split.
- The first element `arr[0]` is the map key.
- The second string, `arr[1]`, is the value which is split
   again, streamed, and converted to a list

```
String[] a = { "A,a,ab,abc", "B,b,bc,bdc" };
Map<String, List<String>> map = Arrays.stream(a)
        .map(str -> str.split(",", 2))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(arr -> arr[0],
                arr -> Arrays.stream(arr[1].split(","))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())));

map.entrySet().foreach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
A=[a, ab, abc]
B=[b, bc, bdc]
```

Comment: This will not handle text files with duplicate keys. Nothing in the question says that cannot happen.

Comment: There was no indication of duplicate keys in the example data.

Comment: *"in the **example** data"* True, but that's just an **example**.

Comment: *"in the example data" True, but that's just an example. – Andreas "*  The OP knows their data better than anyone.  If the OP likes your solution better then that's great.  I only participate on this site to help folks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that support duplicate keys:

```
String[] input = { "A,a,ab,abc", "B,b,bc,bdc", "A,a1,a2,a3" };

Map<String, List<String>> result = Arrays.stream(input)
            .map(e -> e.split(","))
            .filter(a -> a.length >= 2)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    a -> a[0],
                    a -> Arrays.asList(a).subList(1, a.length),
                    (a, b) -> Stream.concat(a.stream(), b.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList())));

System.out.println(result);
```

*Output*

```
{A=[a, ab, abc, a1, a2, a3], B=[b, bc, bdc]}
```